p-table Primeng 11 , Angular 11 , The sort is not working for the data which is in a object
<p-table *ngIf="todayTable && !attendanceLoding" styleClass="p-datatable-striped" [styleClass]="'base-table'"
          [value]="attendanceDatas" [paginator]="false" [rows]="10" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="650px">

          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
              <th  pSortableColumn="name">Name <p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon></th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th pSortableColumn="status">Status <p-sortIcon field="status"></p-sortIcon></th>
              <th>Shift Start Time</th>
              <th>Actual Start Time</th>
              <th>Shift Length</th>
              <th>Actual End Time</th>
              <th pSortableColumn="tracked_duration">Duration <p-sortIcon field="tracked_duration"></p-sortIcon></th>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-employee>
            <tr>
              <td (click)="navigateToUserActivity(employee)">
                {{employee.name}}
              </td>
              <td>{{ employee.attendance[0].date }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.attendance[0].status }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.shift_start }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.attendance[0].startTime }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.shift_hours }}</td>
              <td>{{ employee.attendance[0].endTime }}</td>
              <td>{{ this.commonService.convertTimeOverview(employee.attendance[0].tracked_duration) }}</td>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
        </p-table>

attendanceDatas = [
        {
            "org_id": "6618cd96d99f85a75e028a24",
            "attendance": [
                {
                    "date": "2024-04-12",
                    "startTime": "",
                    "endTime": "",
                    "tracked_duration": 0,
                    "status": "Absent"
                }
            ],
            "user_id": "65f2a61ee921ba41e6c4cac8",
            "name": "Surya Siva",
            "email_id": "surya@gmail.com",
            "shift_start": "11:00 AM",
            "shift_hours": 9
        }
    ]

I have tried custom sort but it is also not working
here i have implemented pSortableColumn for the name and status , but it is working only for name field and not for status , Not sure because of the  "attendance" object

Does this answer your question? Primeng table sorting & filtering based on nested json objects
